# Как определить завершение потока?

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

Как я могу определить завершение этого потока и по его завершению сделать какое-нибудь действие? Возможно ли это? Исполнить это действие в самой функции `func` не могу.

```py
from threading import Thread
x = threading.Thread(target=func)
x.start()
```

Если добавить после строки `x.start()` строку `x.join()`, то программа виснет, до завершения потока, как будто все в главном потоке и выполняется.

Comment: Почему запустить поток, который последовательно вызывает func и делает действие по ее завершению нельзя?

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду сделать действие в самой функции, то нельзя, т.к, там используются GUI элементы, которые могут выполняться только в основном потоке. То есть, мне нужно выполнить функцию в потоке, а по ее завершению и завершению потока, в главном потоке произвести действия над GUI элементами.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать поток, который будет проверять состояние данного потока:

from threading import Thread

```
def func():
    for i in range(10):
        u = [[x,t,y] for x in range(100) for t in range(100) for y in range(100)]

def rev(thread):
    thread.join()
    print('Поток завершил работу.')

x = Thread(target=func)
x_r = Thread(target=rev, args=(x,))
x.start()
x_r.start()
```

Comment: Выглядит как не очень элегантное решение, но спасибо! А есть ли другие варианты?

Comment: @ClarkDevlin есть вариант каждые несколько строк проверять состояние потока, но это ещё хуже. Другого пока что на ум не приходит

Answer (score 0):

есть еще вариант с глобальной переменной

```
import threading
import time

_STATE = [False]


def change_state(fun):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        _STATE[0] = True
        try:
            fun(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            # show exception
            pass
        finally:
            _STATE[0] = False


@change_state
def thr():
    for i in range(10):
        _ = [[x,t,y] for x in range(100) for t in range(100) for y in range(100)]


x = Thread(target=thr)
x.start()
while _STATE[0]:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Хотя не обязательно же чтобы переменная была глобальной, триггер можно и параметром передать. Магия mutable objects